# ASP.NET Core MVC custom authentication and add identity claims manually

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to .NET Core and trying to build the authentication to Azure AD manually. I already have the `CookieAuthentication` to the local SQL database successful using

```
AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>...
```

When user clicks on the "Login Azure" button, it will redirect user to `login.microsoftonline.com/`, then redirect back, then it get the user info from `graph.microsoft.com`. Everything works fine, then it adds the claims and principal, and I verified that the `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` changes to "true" in debugging before redirecting to `Home/Index` page.

However, `@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always false in the `Index` page and I don't see any claims added either.

The login action in the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    string authorizationUrl = string.Format(
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&scope={3}",
    "TenantId", "ClientId", "https://localhost:44369/Azure/AzureReturnCode",
    "openid offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read");

    return Redirect(authorizationUrl);
}

private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async Task<ActionResult> AzureReturnCode(string code)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
        { "client_id", "ClientId"},
        { "code", code},
        { "redirect_uri", "https://localhost:44369/Azure/CatchCode"},
        { "scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read"},
        { "client_secret", "client_secret"},
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);

    //Read back the answer from server
    var responseGraphJSON = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   
    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseGraphJSON);
    var access_token = (res.access_token.Value);

    var respJSON = await Graph_GetUserInfo(access_token);

    var objJSON2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(respJSON);
    var UserId = objJSON2.id.Value;
    var displayName = objJSON2.displayName.Value;
    var mail = objJSON2.mail.Value;
    var userPrincipalName = objJSON2.userPrincipalName.Value;

    bool result = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;  // Testing IsAuthenticated

    var claims = new List<Claim>();
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, displayName));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, mail));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userPrincipalName));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Manager"));

    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { claimsIdentity });
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    HttpContext.User = principal;

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        principal, new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true });

    bool testAuthenticated; 

    if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        testAuthenticated = true;
    } 
    else
    {
        testAuthenticated = false;
    }           

    return Redirect("/Home/Index");
}
```

In the `Index` page, `isAuthenticated` is always false. I expected "true" because I have verified that `isAuthenticated` has changed to "true" before redirecting to this page. Also, the claims are not added, either.

```
<p>IsAuthenticated? @User.Identity.IsAuthenticated</p>

<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <li class="nav-item">Logged In Successful <br/>
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span><br/>
            
        </li>

    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <div>Not Logged In</div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<br />

Test Sign In Data: <br/>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        @foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
        {
            <tr><td>@claim.Type</td><td>@claim.Value</td></tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!